# Is there a single word for "evil mischief"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

In the context of:  he had an "evil mischief" imagination.  I need a single adjective. I'm thinking of someone whose mischief has accessory consequences that are callous/evil, but not through premeditation, rather through ineptness, negligence or indifference.

Comment: *mischievous* but not if for its colloquial definition, which means playful.

Comment: [_Impish_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impish) is listed as a synonym for mischievous, but the connotations of an [_imp_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imp) may suggest evilness more than just mischievous.

Comment: 'wicked' is one I am familiar with, although it, like 'mischief' does imply a lot of "naughty", and perhaps "clever" . I have the same questions that some of the answers have... if you want to convey true 'evil', 'mischief' itself works against you ...  'sick' or "revolting" .. "disturbing" or the many others might work better.

Comment: Not a single word, but ***like a bull in a china shop*** is a common idiom for somebody who causes harm through ineptness, negligence or indifference.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I imagine that it might depend on how much "evil mischief" you are looking to bring across...
Are we talking about **Malcolm Reynolds**, **Dennis the Menace** or **Hannibal Lecter** here?

And, using those as guide-posts, I would proffer:

**misbehaving, irksome** - Malcolm Reynolds

**exasperating, rascally, naughty** - Dennis the Menace

**deleterious, insidious, vicious, malignant** - Hannibal Lecter

HTH.  Let us know.

Comment: For some reason none of these capture the flavor of what I'm looking for.  I'm thinking of someone whose mischief has accessory consequences that are callous/evil, but not through premeditation, rather through ineptness, negligence or indifference.

Comment: @AbAde: That sort of clarification belongs in the question. [Edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/402988/edit) to include it.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason none of these capture the flavor of what I'm looking for. I'm thinking of someone whose mischief has accessory consequences that are callous/evil, but not through premeditation, rather through ineptness, negligence or indifference.

Heedless? Frivolous? Reckless? Careless?